# Magento - using "mage" command line tool locally

Tags: php, magento

I currently have Magento set up on a development server (remote, SSH access) and production server (Cloud instance, SSH access). The current set up is a subversion export to update the development/production servers. This works swell.

If I SSH into the dev server, I can navigate to the Mage root directory and run the following command:

```
./mage install community Namespace_Module
```

This works well on the dev server. However, when I navigate to my local path (on my machine, where I've `svn co`'d Magento), running the `mage` tool always chokes when a `channel` is involved. As an example, I tried:

```
./mage download community Namespace_Module
```

And received the following response:

```
Error:
download: Uri doesn't contain host part
```

I don't understand why this error occurs. I have looked into the mage tool's code and found that the error occurs when the `channel` URL is malformed. (The mage tool is basically a PHP script, and it uses `parse_url` to separate the `channel` URL into the appropriate parts for processing.) However, I am absolutely certain that the setup is identical locally, as it's all in `svn`, and I have tried many iterations of channels in an attempt to make it work locally.

The ultimate goal of all of this is to be able to run the `./mage` tool to install modules on the local system, and commit them to `svn` from there. Ideally, running an `svn status` command should show me all the files that would be added/modified during the installation of the module.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this might be happening and how to make it run locally? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

For anyone wondering, the way I handled this was using the old `pear` command line tool, then running `svn status` to extract the downloaded package pieces into the way our systems are organized. It's definitely not ideal and I am still eagerly hoping to get an answer to my original question, but it's the ugly and painful workaround I'm using in the interim.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the `mage` command line tool, but [this article](http://www.yireo.com/blog/1294-magento-15-mage-command-line) shows some of the channels being supplied as a full URL. Maybe give that a try.

Comment: I'm afraid I've tried that as well, with no luck. (Just tried again to be double sure.) I still get the same error as above, though - "uri doesn't contain host part."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should check whether you have all necessary php extentions installed localy.
Missing php5-curl might be the problem.

Comment: Yes, that was it! I'm running OS X and had to get through the terrors of recompiling PHP with cURL. Amazing, I thought cURL was pretty much standard on every installation of PHP, but apparently OS X (Snow Leopard) doesn't! Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

As you have gotten the code from another server, you might need to reinit things using:

./mage mage-setup

You could also try:

./mage channel-add http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community

Comment: Thanks, but that also doesn't seem to work. I have tried all of the setup/sync functions available to the `mage` tool, to no avail. :(

Comment: Worked perfect for me. Thanks!